# For a systemd template service, status ouput doesn't expand %i in ExecStart

Tags: linux, systemd, rhel, template

The service script correctly starts a bash script with %i expanded in its name, but when I ask for status the %i isn't expanded. Here are the scripts:

```
#cat /etc/systemd/system/test@.service

# The test service unit template file
#
# version=$Header

[Unit]
Description=test %I instance

[Service]
Type=forking
KillMode=process
ExecStart=/bin/bash /tmp/test_service_script_%i 

#cat /tmp/test_service_script_fred

#!/bin/bash

sleep 300&
echo `date`Running $0 > $0.log
```

Running this is OK

```
#systemctl start test@fred
#cat /tmp/test_service_script_fred.log

Thu 12 Oct 14:42:01 BST 2023Running /tmp/test_service_script_fred
```

So far, so good, but

```
#systemctl status test@fred
    ● test@fred.service - test fred instance
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test@.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
    Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-10-12 14:42:01 BST; 6s ago
    Process: 10442 ExecStart=/bin/bash /tmp/test_service_script_%i (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    CGroup: /system.slice/system-test.slice/test@fred.service
           ├─ 9798 sleep 300
           ├─10247 sleep 300
           └─10443 sleep 300
```

Note, line starting "Process:" has unexpanded %i

Should that be expanded, so we can see what it ran?